# Can I chain delegates together?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift-protocols

Swift 4.0 iOS 11.x

I have created a simple text field class, that uses the UITextFieldDelegate. I wanted to add to it an additional protocol that I could use to pass on the fact that the text entry to said field completed. A Delegate chain, since once I have picked up the fact that text entry has exited in the custom class I cannot pass it down to the VC in which the UITextField class is within it seems.

```
import UIKit

protocol ExitedFieldDelegate {
  func exited(info: String)
}

class IDText: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

  internal var zeus: ExitedFieldDelegate? = nil

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    delegate = self
  }

  required override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    delegate = self
  }

  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.textColor = UIColor.black
  }

  func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {
    if (delegate != nil) {
        let info = self.text
        zeus?.exited(info: info!)
    }
  }

}
```

I added this code to the viewController I wanted to use my custom class within.

```
class ConfigViewController: UIViewController, ExitedFieldDelegate
```

And of course the method required by the protocol

```
func exited(info: String) {
    print("The brain has left the room")
}
```

And I made it a delegate of said protocol so I got this in effect

```
var blah = IDText()
blah.delegate = self
```

But well it doesn't work. Am I attempting the impossible here, should I simply use default notifications instead? or indeed something else?

Comment: Please try this blah.zeus = self and remove internal from zeus variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting:

```
blah.delegate = self
```

You are overwriting setting the delegate to `self` in the initializers.

What you want is to rewrite:

```
internal var zeus: ExitedFieldDelegate? = nil
```

to:

```
weak var zeus: ExitedFieldDelegate?
```

To be able to use `weak` (you want that to prevent retain cycle), update protocol definition to:

```
protocol ExitedFieldDelegate: class {
    func exited(info: String)
}
```

And then change this:

```
var blah = IDText()
blah.delegate = self
```

to:

```
var blah = IDText()
// you want to set zeus instead of the delegate field
blah.zeus = self
```

Comment: Just a note that the protocol will need `class` as `protocol ExitedFieldDelegate: class` for `weak` to be possible.